# How to create product attributes on Shopify store?

Tags: attributes, shopify, product

I'm new to development on Shopify. I have experience with Magento store.

On Magento you could create product attributes like:

- short description
- additional title

Basically whatever you wanted to show up on product page or on product listing you could add.

On Shopify I dont see such an option. It has variants, but variants affect pricing and weight. I just need to output some additional info about the product and be able to call on it through a forloop.

Any ideas? Maybe some kind of plugin?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

I found something about shopify meta fields:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1odr-fmWAk

It seems very strange that this is not a baked into Shopify store directly.

UPDATE:

Found some apps if anybody wonders:
https://apps.shopify.com/metafields-editor-2?surface_detail=metafields&surface_inter_position=1&surface_intra_position=1&surface_type=search

and Chrome plugins:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shopifyfd-dashboard-tool/lffljkleilfpjlmcdnoaghhcbnemelge/related

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shopify-metafields-master/cjncpboimbjaokmddpdengkckeflpjfo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Additional information outside of the scope of the content that must be different for each product can only be done via metafields. ( or complex liquid logic )

So if you like to add different information for each separate product you should look into a Metafield app for Shopify: https://apps.shopify.com/search?q=metafields&st_source= ( there are free ones as well )

---

Other options will be to use pages with the same name of the product, section with blocks where you can select the product and enter the content in a richtext field... But all of these will require additional steps for the administrator, and if you are not building this for yourself it's recommended to use an Metafield App instead.